# Find last element in array from a specific index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to make a function that will navigate the user to the steps that are not disabled, and that skips the disabled steps.

I wrote the following code, but it does not behave how i would like it to.

Expected behaviour assuming the current step is Step 5:

On Button Click Step 5 to Step 3 on Button click  Step 3 to Step 1

But currently the behaviour is like this:

On button click Step 5 to Step 1

I want to make the loop the stop on step 3, i tried to add a breakpoint, but that did not solve it, i am running out of ideas

```js
 const steps = [
  { title: 'Step 1', id: 'stp1', disabled: false, },
  { title: 'Step 2', id: 'stp2', disabled: true,  },
  { title: 'Step 3', id: 'stp3', disabled: false, },
  { title: 'Step 4', id: 'stp4', disabled: true,  },
  { title: 'Step 5', id: 'stp5', disabled: false, },
]

const [currentStepIndex, setCurrentStepIndex] = useState(4);

const getPreviousSelectableStep = () => {
  const steps = args.steps
  let stepIndex = currentStepIndex

  if ((stepIndex > 0) && steps[stepIndex - 1].disabled === true) {
    for (var i = steps.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (steps[i].disabled === false) {
        setCurrentStepIndex(i)
        setCurrentStepId(steps[i].id)
        break
      }
    }
  } else if (stepIndex > 0) {
    setCurrentStepIndex(stepIndex - 1)
    setCurrentStepId(steps[stepIndex - 1].id)
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to see what you do with `getPreviousSelectableStep`, since you are creating a closure on `currentStepIndex` (using it in scope) but it's a `useState` hook.  So I'm not sure when you are expecting the `currentStepIndex` to change.

Comment: where are you calling `getPreviousSelectableStep` from? it's possible you're triggering multiple react renders with 1 user input which is leading to an unexpected result

Comment: "On Button Click Step 5 to Step 3 on Button click Step 3 to Step 1" seems to say If on Step 5 and ckick, go BACK to Step 3 and if on Step 3 to BACK to Step 1" Please add clarity of the intent here by adding notes to that effect which is the inverse of what  "stepped" process would typically be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `if` condition start the loop from `startIndex - 1` and not from the end `steps.length - 1`.

```
  if (stepIndex > 0 && steps[stepIndex - 1].disabled === true) {
    for (var i = stepIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (steps[i].disabled === false) {
        setCurrentStepIndex(i);
        setCurrentStepId(steps[i].id);
        break;
      }
    }
  } else if (stepIndex > 0) {
    setCurrentStepIndex(stepIndex - 1);
    setCurrentStepId(steps[stepIndex - 1].id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPrevStep(number)
{
    let data = steps.filter(x => !x.disabled).reverse()
    return data[data.findIndex(x => x.id == "stp" + number) + 1]
}
```